# PowerShell / Registry, change to Best Performance, and activate the change

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-registry, themes

The following is listed on various sites to switch to Best Performance mode (under This Computer Properties > Advanced system settings > Performance). On running this nothing happens. I can see that the options are altered in the Performance dialogue, but I've tried restarting Explorer (and also the "Themes" service as that was listed as being required).

What will I need to do to get the below settings to also be activated on the system?

```
####################
#
# Adjust for Best Performance setting (in Performance > Visual Effects)
# Note that this requires that the "Themes" service is restarted
# https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/73d72328-38ed-4abe-a65d-83aaad0f9047/adjust-for-best-performance?forum=winserverpowershell
#
####################

$out = @'
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; ###
; Visual Effects
; ###

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000002

; Do not Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
"MinAnimate"="0"

; Disable Animations in Taskbar and Start Menu
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"TaskbarAnimations"=0
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"TaskbarAnimations"=-

; Disable desktop composition
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"CompositionPolicy"=0

; Enable transparent glass
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"ColorizationOpaqueBlend"=0

; Disable Taskbar Thumbnail Previews
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM]
"AlwaysHibernateThumbnails"=dword:00000000

; Disable Explorer Thumbnails (All Users)
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"DisableThumbnails"=dword:00000001

; Disable translucent selection rectangle
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"ListviewAlphaSelect"=0

; Dont show window contents while dragging
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"DragFullWindows"=0

; Dont smooth Edges of Screen Fonts
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"FontSmoothing"="0"

; Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"ListviewShadow"=0

; Disable visual styles on windows and buttons
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ThemeManager]
"ThemeActive"="0"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ThemeManager]
"ThemeActive"=-

; Disable following:
; * Animate controls and elements inside windows
; * Smooth-scroll list boxes
; * Slide open combo boxes
; * Fade or slide menus into view
; * Show shadows under mouse pointer
; * Fade or slide ToolTips into view
; * Fade out menu items after clicking
; * Show shadows under windows
; * Use Visual styles on windows and buttons
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"UserPreferencesMask"=hex:90,12,01,80,10,00,00,00
'@

$out | Out-File -FilePath "$Env:TEMP\AdjustForBestPerformanceVisual.reg" -Force -Encoding oem
Invoke-Command { reg import "$Env:TEMP\AdjustForBestPerformanceVisual.reg" *>&1 | Out-Null }
# Must restart the Themes service
Restart-Service Themes -Force
```

Comment: The registry keys are written, but the Performance settings are *not* applied to the GUI as per post. I can even go into the Performance dialogue and see that things *are* altered, but nothing is activated. To activate, "Apply" is greyed out, so I need to check one or more boxes in there, then press "Apply" again, and only *then* are the settings activated. For registry changes for Explorer, I automate an Explorer restart to apply a change, but for this restarting Explorer (or Themes) does not work.